# Ruby | Trying to check password by comparing to a file

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I have some troubles with my code using Ruby. its just for a terminal program, so no website or anything.

In my code I Will have the user create a login. Then I will have the user to login, but I cant seem to figure out how to check if password or username is correct.

The program should compare whatever the user types in as a username/password with the file (userdatabase) - I think i got that right.

Now I am trying to stop the user if the input is not found in the user database, using a while loop, but i cant seem to make that work.

Code:

```
puts "What will be your user name?"
```

`username = gets.chomp`

```
puts "What will be your password?"

password = gets.chomp

puts "Please repeat your password."

passwordsafe = gets.chomp



f = File.new("student.txt", "w+")
f.puts username + ";" + password + ";"  + passwordsafe
f.close

puts "well done, you have created a new user."

lines = IO.readlines("student.txt")
lines.each{|line| print(line)}


puts "now you need to login."
puts "What is your username?"
username = gets.chomp

File.open("student.txt") do |f|
  f.any? do |line|
    while line.include?(username)
  end
end

elsif puts "Sorry your username was incorrect"
end

#lines = IO.readlines("student.txt")
#lines.each{|line| (line)}

puts "what is your password?"
password = gets.chomp
```

Comment: If you're learning about passwords it's time to learn about [safe password hashing](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby).

Answer (score 0):

The `while` is unnecessary.

The username check currently like this:

```
File.open("student.txt") do |f|
  f.any? do |line|
    while line.include?(username)
  end
end
```

Could be like this:

```
File.open("student.txt").each_line.any? do |line| 
  line.include?(username)
end
```

Or collapsed to a single line like this:

```
File.open("student.txt").each_line.any?{ |l| l.include?(username) }
```

Check the docs on the `any?` method to make sure you understand what it's expecting: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

As for the rest of the syntax errors, I'll leave those up to you ;)

Comment: oh, so i have removed the 'elsif' now it seems to work fine. But my problem is that i want it to go back and ask for the username again if its not in the database - how do i do that?